# Would assigning the bits of a variable from calculating be possible?

Tags: verilog, vivado

I'm learning about how to better build faster adders and I'm learning about generate/propagate adders. In one of my lines of code, I have this:

```
assign G[3:0] = X[3:0] & Y[3:0];
```

Would this cause an error or would it calculate and assign a bit to its respective bit position in G?
Note: I am using Verilog/Vivado.

Comment: That should work - are you encountering an error, and/or are you seeing unexpected results in your simulator, hardware, or elaborated/synthesized schematics? If so, can you [edit] your post to add details about the unexpected results or errors?

Comment: @nanofarad I writing up a rough draft for my lab and just wanted to know beforehand, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This will work as you are expecting. The bitwise operators will produce a result of the same width as the largest of the two operands (the smaller will be grown by padding or sign extension).

As both of your operands are set to 4 bit, then you will get a 4 bit result from the bitwise AND. These four bits will then be assigned to the selected four bits of the assignment target.

Furthermore, if `G`, `Y`, and `X` are all declared as 4-bit variables, the `[3:0]` becomes unnecessary as the bitwise operation will still be 4 bit due to the variable width.

---

If you were instead to use the logical AND (`&&`) this would not work as expected - `G[3:0]` would be set to either `4'b0` if both `X[3:0]` and `Y[3:0]` were `4'b0`, or set to `4'b1` otherwise.